# Why @use is not working but @import is working in this scenario?

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I want the `_typography.scss` access variables on `_variables.scss` .

```
// _variables.scss
$color: <null> | <$variable> | <value> | <etc>;

// _typography.scss
body {color: $color;}
```

When I try:

```
//_typography.css

@use  '_variables.scss'
body:{color: $color;} / Error undefined variable. color: $color;
```

But when I try:

```
//_typography.css
@import  '_variables.scss'
body:{color: $color;} / works as intended.
```

Since Sass is migrating from @import to @use, why the @use doesnt work as expected in this case?
And what would be the best practice to avoid this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to Forward before you use. Put the typo and variables in a folder named abstracts together, and create an index.scss file. Inside the index file do this: forward "variables"; and forward "typography". Then above every scss file that comes after do this use '../abstracts' as *; Then you wil have access to all your variables. Put @ in front of forward and use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `@use`, your imports have a [namespace](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#choosing-a-namespace) by default. You can either use the namespace:

```
@use "variables";
body: { color: variables.$color; }
```

Or remove it with `@use "<url>" as *`:

```
@use "variables" as *;
body: { color: $color; }
```

The best practice is to read the doc. ;)